# Empty results when I store records in array, repeat them to reach certain nr and use foreach to display them

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

This is what my code does:
it gets 4 rows from my table, stores them in an array, repeats them untill they reach 20 inside that array then echo's them whit a foreach loop... problem is i get an empty result at the end of each foreach cycle of the 4 results.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$table."");
            $row_nr = mysql_num_rows($result); // Find out how many rows I have in the table, lets say 4


        while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $arrayrows[] = $rows; // Put my 4 rows in the array
            }   

        // Now I multiply nr. of rows to reach desired number which is 20
        $dbRow=0;
        for($n=0; $n <= 20; $n++)
        {
        if($dbRow > $row_nr) $dbRow = 0;
        $fullarrayrows[$n] = $arrayrows[$dbRow];
        $dbRow++;
        }

        // after some php pagination code I slice the array:
        $arrayslice = array_slice($fullarrayrows, $offset, $rowsperpage);

        // Now i display my array
        foreach($arrayslice as $slice) 
        {
            echo ''.$slice['name'].'';
            echo '<br />';
        }
```

**Problem is I get some empty records in the foreach

name1
name2
name3
name4
HERE I GET THE EMPTY ENTRY
name1
name2
name3
name4
AGAIN I GET THE EMPTY ENTRY

... and so on, at the end of each cycle**

Thank you very much , please give me an ideea of what's wrong:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$dbRow` indexes start at 0 and end at 3
but `$row_nr` equals 4

so change this line

```
if($dbRow > $row_nr) $dbRow = 0;
```

to

```
if($dbRow >= $row_nr) $dbRow = 0;
```